html2canvas issues chrome extension
I am trying to use the html2canvas within a chrome extension I am building.
For my chrome extension I am directly injecting JS so that the user can toggle the extension so it does not go out of focus and closes when the user clicks on the current tab.

<body>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>

I am choosing to dynamically load the html2canvas from a local file where I have copied the JS file.
I am loading it within my content.js file (this file also contains the UI where it is directly injecting into the current tab DOM.
Here is the function where I am calling the html2canvas to load:
  async function mouseUpHandler(e) {
      if (!isSelecting) return;
    
      isSelecting = false;
    
      // Remove event listeners and overlay
      const overlay = document.getElementById("selectionOverlay");
      overlay.removeEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownHandler);
      overlay.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler);
      overlay.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpHandler);
      document.body.removeChild(overlay);
    
      // Get the selected area coordinates
      const rect = selectionBox.getBoundingClientRect();
    
      // Remove the selection boxhtm
      selectionBox.remove();
    
      console.log("Selected area:", rect);
    
      try {
        // Wait for html2canvas to be loaded
        await loadHtml2Canvas();
    
        // Ensure window.html2canvas is loaded and then use it
        window.html2canvas(document.body, {
          x: rect.left + window.scrollX,
          y: rect.top + window.scrollY,
          width: rect.width,
          height: rect.height,
          windowWidth: document.documentElement.scrollWidth,
          windowHeight: document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
          scale: window.devicePixelRatio // Adjust for high-DPI screens
        })
        .then((canvas) => {
          const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
          console.log("Captured image data URL:", dataUrl);
    
          // Store the captured image data URL
          capturedImageDataUrl = dataUrl;
    
          // Display the captured image in the sidebar
          displayCapturedImage(dataUrl);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('html2canvas error:', error);
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
      }
    }
    

And here is the loadhtml2canvas:
  function loadHtml2Canvas() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Check if html2canvas is already loaded
        if (typeof window.html2canvas !== 'undefined') {
          console.log('html2canvas is already loaded.');
          resolve(); // Resolve immediately if already loaded
          return;
        }
    
        // Load html2canvas dynamically
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        const scriptUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL('html2canvas.min.js');
        console.log('Loading html2canvas from:', scriptUrl);
        
        script.src = scriptUrl;
    
        script.onload = function() {
          console.log('html2canvas loaded dynamically.');
          if (typeof window.html2canvas !== 'undefined') {
            resolve(); // Resolve the promise if window.html2canvas is defined
          } else {
            reject(new Error('window.html2canvas is still not defined after loading.'));
          }
        };
    
        script.onerror = function() {
          reject(new Error('Failed to load html2canvas.'));
        };
    
        // Append the script to the document head
        document.head.appendChild(script);
      });
    }

What is happening is it looks like it is correctly being loaded from the file but then it turns out to be undefined.
Here is the console.log statements:
Selected area: DOMRect {x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0, top: 0, …}
content.js:409 Loading html2canvas from: chrome-extension://geekmcfbhphgbnafmfmcmhjeaeoaikod/html2canvas.min.js
content.js:414 html2canvas loaded dynamically.
content.js:482 window.html2canvas is still not defined after loading.
mouseUpHandler @ content.js:482
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried to load this from the manifest.js like so:
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["html2canvas.min.js", "content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["html2canvas.min.js"], 
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ]

I get the same error

Remove web_accessible_resources and loadHtml2Canvas, because it already has loaded in content_scripts and is directly available as html2canvas.

Do i need to reference it as 'window.html2canvas'?

window. prefix is unnecessary.
